# What is a built-in name for a filehandle in Perl?

Tags: perl, filehandle

None of the names listed by [perl -f ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) seems to be for a filehandle. The following code returns GLOB, so it seems that filehandle is internally mapped to or managed as a typeglob. Is that correct?

```
open FH, '>', "out.txt";
my $ref = \*FH;
print "ref \$ref:", ref $ref, "\n";
```

Does a filehandle have its own type name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Does a filehandle have its own type name?*

[`IO`](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/be2c0c650b028f54e427f2469a59942edfdff8a9:/perl.h#l2637).

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'Dump(*STDOUT{IO});'
SV = IV(0x3ba7118) at 0x3ba7128
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x3bc4390
  SV = PVIO(0x3bc8668) at 0x3bc4390
    REFCNT = 3
    FLAGS = (OBJECT)
    STASH = 0x3bc3fa0   "IO::File"
    IFP = 0x3bbe180
    OFP = 0x3bbe180
    DIRP = 0x0
    LINES = 0
    PAGE = 0
    PAGE_LEN = 60
    LINES_LEFT = 0
    TOP_GV = 0x0
    FMT_GV = 0x0
    BOTTOM_GV = 0x0
    TYPE = '>'
    FLAGS = 0x0
```

Technically, an `IO` object can have three handles associated with it: An input file handle (`IFP`), an output file handle (`OFP`), and a directory handle (e.g. created using `opendir`, `DIRP`). Usually, only one of the input and output handles are set, or they are both set to the same handle. Doing `open(FOO, ...); opendir(FOO, ...); <FOO>; readdir(FOO);` would work fine because of the separate file and directory handles.

> *it seems filehandle is internally mapped to or managed as a typeglob. Is that correct?*

Both file and directory IO objects are normally encapsulated in a glob, yes.
But it's not required.

```
$ perl -E'
   my $fh = "STDOUT";     say($fh "$fh");
   my $fh = *STDOUT;      say($fh "$fh");
   my $fh = \*STDOUT;     say($fh "$fh");
   my $fh = *STDOUT{IO};  say($fh "$fh");
'
STDOUT                    # Name
*main::STDOUT             # Glob
GLOB(0x1175a48)           # Reference to a glob. (This is returned by open $fh)
IO::File=IO(0x1175a60)    # Reference to a (blessed) IO.
```

Comment: How can you have separate input/output handles in the same IO object?

Comment: One for input (reading) and one for output (writing). I don't know if they can be different except in the case of one being null.

Comment: How do you make one of them null?

Comment: `open my $fh, "<", ...`

Comment: Or rather, that makes one of them not null :)